# Where is the atomicblender utility panel?

Tags: interface, add-on

This feels like such a basic question, but I'm just getting started with Blender. I want to use it to look at some .pdb files, so I'm using the [atomicblender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/mesh_atomic.html) addon. I have successfully imported my file, but I can't find the utility panel. Where does it appear for this addon?
[image: .pdb file and blender sucess]

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE:  The question wants this panel:

[image: Utility side panel]

It is found in the *Create* tab of the sidebar (highlighted).  The sidebar's visibility is toggled using the <kbd>N</kbd> key.  It is only available if "utility panel" is checked, as it is in the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Maybe I wasn't clear. What I'm looking for is this toolbar shown here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/mesh_atomic.html#measure-distances

Comment: Sometimes they add a tab to the N-panel.  Hover your mouse over the main viewport window and press N to open a side panel.

Comment: @GermanBarcenas Sorry I missed the point of your question.  I've updated the answer.  Most add-ons if they add a panel will add it to the side bar or otherwise tell you where to find it in the add-on description.

Comment: Yes that `N` helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find the Utilities Panel either. In my case (Blender 3.1.2 on Mac) the option for the Utilities Panel was disabled by default in the add-on menu —bottom-most checkbox.

Once activated, it was there in the Object tab.
One needs to press `A` to select the molecule and change the atoms to tetrahedra or what-not.

[image: addon disabled]